# Best way to get a static DateTime value

Tags: c#, static-members

Is there a better way to get a static DateTime value in C# than the following?

```
public static DateTime StartOfRecordedHistory = DateTime.Parse("2004-01-01");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static DateTime StartOfRecordedHistory = new DateTime(2004, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static readonly DateTime StartOfRecordedHistory = new DateTime(2004, 1, 1);
```

No more elegant, I admit, but it avoids any issues with locale-dependent date parsing.

If you're looking for date-time literals, unfortunately C# doesn't provide them.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
public static DateTime StartOfRecordedHistory = new DateTime(2004, 1, 1)
```

is probably the best way as, as it's been pointed out, it doesn't have any issues with different date-time formats.

There are numerous creators for a DateTime - see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime.aspx), so you can have the exact format of date you want.